# NGINX TCP Load Balancing is ip-sticky when it should be random, per request

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, tcp

I have an NGINX server being used as a TCP load balancer.  It is default to round-robin load balancing, so my expectation is that for a given client IP, every time they hit the endpoint they will get a different backend upstream server for each request.  But instead what is happening is that they get the same upstream server every time, and each **distinct** client IP is getting a distinct upstream server.  This is bad because my clients generate a lot of traffic and it is causing hotspots because any given client can only utilize one upstream server.  It seems to slowly rotate a given client IP across the upstream servers; again I want it to randomly assign each request to an upstream per request.

How can I make NGINX randomely assign the upstream server for *every request*?  I tried the random keyword and this had no effect.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

stream {

    upstream api_backend_http {
        server node1.mydomain.com:80;
        server node2.mydomain.com:80;
        server node6.mydomain.com:80;
        server node14.mydomain.com:80;
        server node18.mydomain.com:80;
        server node19.mydomain.com:80;
        server node21.mydomain.com:80;
        server node22.mydomain.com:80;
        server node24.mydomain.com:80;
    }

    upstream api_backend_https {
        server node1.mydomain.com:443;
        server node2.mydomain.com:443;
        server node6.mydomain.com:443;
        server node14.mydomain.com:443;
        server node18.mydomain.com:443;
        server node19.mydomain.com:443;
        server node21.mydomain.com:443;
        server node22.mydomain.com:443;
        server node24.mydomain.com:443;
    }

    server {
        listen            80;
        proxy_pass        api_backend_http;
        proxy_buffer_size 16k;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1s;
    }

    server {
        listen            443;
        proxy_pass        api_backend_https;
        proxy_buffer_size 16k;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1s;
    }

    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you should stop using nginx as a TCP load balancer **for other Web-servers** and switch it to a full-fledged HTTP reverse-proxy, which it is. That way you will get the per-request RR, which you want (with persistent connections disabled by default), instead of TCP session distribution.

Comment: But isn't it supposed to distribute the requests in TCP mode?  @drookie

Comment: It should and it does. Just not the way you want, because you're using it wrong.

Comment: This answer is totally unhelpful and vague because it does not actually answer the question.  The question is how to fix the issue.

Comment: You won’t get any other, because the original question was a perverted example of setting up things. And that’s the educational part.